# MSMQ failing to send over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, msmq, fiddler

I have been trying to get my MSMQ to pass messages over HTTPS without success.  All outgoing messages sit in a queue with status "Waiting to connect".

This is not the case for messages over HTTP, they are received without issue.

I've created a Certificate Authority on the receiving machine, downloaded the cert chain and CA cert, installing under Trusted Root (Local Computer and Current User profiles).

I then exported the CA cert and installed that on the sending machine (under TRCA - Local Computer and Current User)

I have been able to navigate to the target MSMQ using internet explorer, this usually give a 501 not implemented error.

[image]

I don't really know why this isn't working and it's pretty fraustrating.

What other approaches can I take to get this to work??

Cheers

Niall

Comment: I have also created a Server Authentication certificate, that has the same name as the receiving machines domain name.  Should this be necessary in a basic scenario?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that the server isn't properly accepting the HTTPS connection from the client.

You'll need to add more information to your question, including details of how you attempted to bind the Server Authentication certificate to the endpoint on which your server is listening.